# bug with backrefalt and natbib's sort&compress

Tags: natbib, bugs

I encountered a bug between `natbib`'s `sort&compress` and the `backrefalt` feature to locate the section of citation in the bib.

Here is a short template to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,pagebackref]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
  \ifcase #1 %
    (Not cited.) %
  \or
    {(Referenced on page #2.)}%
  \else
    {(Referenced on pages #2.)}%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand*{\backrefsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{ and }
\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{, and }

\begin{document}

\cite{cite1,cite2,cite3}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{my}

\end{document}
```

assuming three consecutive citations `cite1,cite2,cite3` in `my.bib`. The result will appear as *[1-3]*, and the citation 2 will appear as *(Not cited)*.

I switched from `sort&compress` to `sort` to avoid this bug, but is there a way to have both the compress and the correct back references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this patch:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,pagebackref]{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
  \ifcase #1 %
    (Not cited.) %
  \or
    {(Referenced on page #2.)}%
  \else
    {(Referenced on pages #2.)}%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand*{\backrefsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{ and }
\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{, and }
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\NAT@citexnum{\let\NAT@last@num\NAT@num}{\MakeLinkTarget[cite]{}\Hy@backout{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}\let\NAT@last@num\NAT@num}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite{doody,herrmann,angenendt}


\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When running `pdflatex` after `bibtex`, I get the error: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \MakeLinkTarget

Comment: Then your tex system is too old. Try with \phantomsection instead.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my TeX system and it works great. Quite some magic here!