Backref not working for compressed citation
I used the following code in the header of my thesis in order to compress citations, but also include backref in my Reference section :
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref} 
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\newcommand{\myfontbackref}[1]{
    \hspace*{\fill} \mbox{\small #1}
}

\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
\ifcase #1 \myfontbackref{Not cited}
    \or \myfontbackref{Cited on page #2}
    \else \myfontbackref{#1 citations on pages #2}
\fi
}

But there are examples in my text were I cite multiples sources like so : \cite{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4}. They then appear as [1-4] (and this is what I want).
But then, in the actual Reference section, ref2 and ref3 will appear as "Not cited", while ref1 and ref4 works properly and appear with "N citations on pages X, Y and Z"
What am I missing here? Sorry if that is obvious!
Cheers y'all :)

you are missing a complete example that can be used for a test.

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688896/bug-with-backrefalt-and-natbibs-sortcompress

I missed that, sorry! thanks a lot :)
