The backref subpackage of hyperref has omissions: it fails to generate back-references for certain citations
Some backlinks provided by \usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref} failed to show up.
Uncertain whether the issue lies with backref.sty or the sn-article-template.
MWE.tex below should work with sn-article-template through either overleaf or springernature:
\documentclass[backref=page,sn-nature]{sn-jnl}% Style for submissions to Nature Portfolio journals

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
%%%%

\begin{document}

Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa
ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend
at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem.is given (and the transfer-matrix method (TMM) should be employed to address the issues of multiple reflections and transmissions \cite{yehElectromagneticPropagationBirefringent1979,liPhotonicBandStructures2003,mackayTransferMatrixMethodElectromagnetics2020}), which means neither the divergence equations \cite{chenWavevectorspaceMethodWave1993,nelsonDerivingTransmissionReflection1995,landryCompleteMethodDetermine1995,abdulhalimExactMatrixMethod1999,mcleodVectorFourierOptics2014,asoubarSimulationBirefringenceEffects2015,changWavePropagationBianisotropic2014,chernChiralSurfaceWaves2017} nor boundary conditions \cite{chenWavevectorspaceMethodWave1993,nelsonDerivingTransmissionReflection1995} are even required.

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
    \expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax
    \def\url#1{\burl{#1}}\fi
    \expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi
    \providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
    \providecommand{\eprint}[2][]{\url{#2}}
    \providecommand{\doi}[1]{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}
    \bibcommenthead
    
    \bibitem{yehElectromagneticPropagationBirefringent1979}
    \bibinfo{author}{Yeh, P.}
    \newblock \bibinfo{title}{Electromagnetic propagation in birefringent layered
        media} .
    
    \bibitem{liPhotonicBandStructures2003}
    \bibinfo{author}{Li, Z.-Y.} \& \bibinfo{author}{Lin, L.-L.}
    \newblock \bibinfo{title}{Photonic band structures solved by a plane-wave-based
        transfer-matrix method} .
    
    \bibitem{mackayTransferMatrixMethodElectromagnetics2020}
    \bibinfo{author}{Mackay, T.~G.} \& \bibinfo{author}{Lakhtakia, A.}
    \newblock \emph{\bibinfo{title}{The {{Transfer-Matrix Method}} in
            {{Electromagnetics}} and {{Optics}}}} Synthesis {{Lectures}} on
    {{Electromagnetics}} (\bibinfo{publisher}{Springer International
        Publishing}).
    \newblock \urlprefix\url{https://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-3-031-02022-3}.
    
    \bibitem{chenWavevectorspaceMethodWave1993}
    \bibinfo{author}{Chen, B.} \& \bibinfo{author}{Nelson, D.~F.}
    \newblock \bibinfo{title}{Wave-vector-space method for wave propagation in
        bounded media} \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{48}}, \bibinfo{pages}{15365--15371}.
    \newblock \urlprefix\url{https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.48.15365}.
    
    \bibitem{nelsonDerivingTransmissionReflection1995}
    \bibinfo{author}{Nelson, D.~F.}
    \newblock \bibinfo{title}{Deriving the transmission and reflection coefficients
        of an optically active medium without using boundary conditions}
    \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{51}}, \bibinfo{pages}{6142--6153}.
    \newblock \urlprefix\url{https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevE.51.6142}.
    
    \bibitem{landryCompleteMethodDetermine1995}
    \bibinfo{author}{Landry, G.~D.} \& \bibinfo{author}{Maldonado, T.~A.}
    \newblock \bibinfo{title}{Complete method to determine transmission and
        reflection characteristics at a planar interface between arbitrarily oriented
        biaxial media} \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{12}}, \bibinfo{pages}{2048}.
    \newblock
    \urlprefix\url{https://opg.optica.org/abstract.cfm?URI=josaa-12-9-2048}.
    
    \bibitem{abdulhalimExactMatrixMethod1999}
    \bibinfo{author}{Abdulhalim, I.}
    \newblock \bibinfo{title}{Exact 2 \texttimes{} 2 matrix method for the
        transmission and reflection at the interface between two arbitrarily oriented
        biaxial crystals} \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{1}}, \bibinfo{pages}{655--661}.
    \newblock
    \urlprefix\url{https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1464-4258/1/6/301}.
    
    \bibitem{mcleodVectorFourierOptics2014}
    \bibinfo{author}{McLeod, R.~R.} \& \bibinfo{author}{Wagner, K.~H.}
    \newblock \bibinfo{title}{Vector {{Fourier}} optics of anisotropic materials}
    \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{6}}, \bibinfo{pages}{368}.
    \newblock
    \urlprefix\url{https://opg.optica.org/aop/abstract.cfm?uri=aop-6-4-368}.
    
    \bibitem{asoubarSimulationBirefringenceEffects2015}
    \bibinfo{author}{Asoubar, D.}, \bibinfo{author}{Zhang, S.} \&
    \bibinfo{author}{Wyrowski, F.}
    \newblock \bibinfo{title}{Simulation of birefringence effects on the dominant
        transversal laser resonator mode caused by anisotropic crystals}
    \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{23}}, \bibinfo{pages}{13848}.
    \newblock
    \urlprefix\url{https://opg.optica.org/abstract.cfm?URI=oe-23-11-13848}.
    
    \bibitem{changWavePropagationBianisotropic2014}
    \bibinfo{author}{Chang, P.-H.}, \bibinfo{author}{Kuo, C.-Y.} \&
    \bibinfo{author}{Chern, R.-L.}
    \newblock \bibinfo{title}{Wave propagation in bianisotropic metamaterials:
        Angular selective transmission} .
    
    \bibitem{chernChiralSurfaceWaves2017}
    \bibinfo{author}{Chern, R.-L.} \& \bibinfo{author}{Yu, Y.-Z.}
    \newblock \bibinfo{title}{Chiral surface waves on hyperbolic-gyromagnetic
        metamaterials} .
    
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

It appears that this issue is neither attributable to the backref.sty nor the sn-template, but rather stems from the natbib.sty (which has nothing to do with the sn-template :) — see patch tex.stackexchange.com/a/688905/309711





I will not follow an external link to test this. You should provide a small example here.

Hello! To help us text and fix your problem, please provide a minimal working example, as explained here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

How to merge sn-jnl.cls & sn-nature.bst & sn-article.tex into the MWE ?...

Remove parts from the files (binary search is your friend) such that the files are minimal with respect to content and the error persists.

try with this patch https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688905/2388

the external link to files has now been replaced by 1 MWE.tex + 2 links to sn-template :)

@UlrikeFischer, it works, thanks!

They are the same. how could I merge this post into that one? or just leave this post here as its synonym?
